# Python, pandas categorical numbers on multiple columns and data frames

Tags: pandas, multiple-columns, categorical-data

I have multiple columns that contain string codes that I want to turn into unique categorical numbers. That I need for machine learning where strings can not be used directly.

The part that makes my problem a bit more complex is that my data set is split to separate data frames that I want to keep them at the end of the processing separate.

In the past I was able to overcome the problem for the case of a single column, where the string codes were in a single column. The code below helped me do that:

```
# merge the different data frames as one by using dict

    X=pd.concat(dict(enumerate([X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5, X_6, X_7, X_8, X_9, X_10])))
    X=X.loc[:, X.columns.str.startswith('var1')+X.columns.str.startswith('var2(t-1)')] #keep all the var1 variables(RSRP) and only the last one from the Geohashses var2(t-1)
        Geo_as_Category=pd.Series(X['var2(t-1)'], dtype="category") #turn Geohash to categorical
        X['GeohashFeature']=Geo_as_Category.cat.codes
        [X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5, X_6, X_7, X_8, X_9, X_10]=[d.xs(k) for k, d in X.groupby(level=0)]
```

where the dict was helping me to merge the different dataframes in a structure that later on would allow me to separate them back as well.

Now my problem is a bit more complex since the code strings are split over multiple columns so I need a way after merging all data frames together with the

```
    X=pd.concat(dict(enumerate([X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5, X_6, X_7, X_8, X_9, X_10])))
```

to take into consideration all the columns for building the unique codes and not just a single column as I was doing here

```
    Geo_as_Category=pd.Series(X['var2(t-1)'], dtype="category") 
    X['GeohashFeature']=Geo_as_Category.cat.codes
```

Can you help me think of a way of doing that?

Thanks a lot
Alex

Comment: one hot encoding may help you do that without doing it by hand, it is available is almost (all?) machine learning librairies, here is the link for sklearn https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html . Also it is better to have one hot columns that regular categorical columns (like class 1 2 3) because when you have 1 2 3 it implies that 3 is bigger than 2 etc

Comment: sorry but you misunderstood the post. All columns contains a small string that is geographical feature. I need to take into account all columns for assigning those codes.